# How to fix the error with more variables than parameters in mysqli_stmt_bind_param() method

Tags: php, mysqli

I was learning how to add values to the database with PHP and I have the problem with some code bellow where I want to add values to the database.

I tried this code bellow but every time I get this Warning: **mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\path\to\the\file.php on line 38**

The line 38 is the line with the *mysqli_stmt_bind_param()* method

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO times(uid,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,t12,t13,t14,t15,t16,t17,t18,t19,t20) VALUES ('?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?',?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit();
  }
  else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssssssssssss", $uid, $a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $t12, $t13, $t14, $t15, $t16, $t17, $t18, $t19, $t20);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    echo "done!";
  }
```

The *uid, a, b, c, d, e, f* and *g* columns in the database are *TINYTEXT* type and the other columns are *TINYINT(1)* type.

There are 17 question marks in the $sql variable and exact 17 s's and parameters in the *mysqli_stmt_bind_param()* methon in the line 38.
I was expecting that the values will be added into the table in my database but I can see just this warning on the website and there are no values in the database.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first line to:

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO times(uid,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,t12,t13,t14,t15,t16,t17,t18,t19,t20) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

The parameter markers `?` should not be quoted in the SQL statement.

Comment: Thank you, it worked.
But how does this work with my database?
If I manually want to add some values for uid, a, b, c, d, e, f, and g and if I type them without the single quotes, I become the error.

Comment: Right, it only works for prepared statements, not regular `INSERT/UPDATE`/etc.  See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 0):

Try **not** putting your question mark placeholders inside single quotes. `'?'` is a character string consisting of a single question mark. It is *not* a placeholder for a parameter.

Comment: Thank you, it worked.
But how does this work with my database?
If I manually want to add some values for uid, a, b, c, d, e, f, and g and if I type them without the single quotes, I become the error.

Comment: I am not sure i follow your followup question. When you bind parameters, you supply one value for each bare question mark Place holder. Anything else is a literal e.g ```insert into x values (1, ?, 'hello', ?);``` consists of 2 literals (1 and 'hello') and 2 placeholders which must be bound later in youf code.

Comment: If this has helped you, can you please accept the answer that has helped you the most?